# Creating an edgelist with multiple columns and N/As in R

Tags: r, bigdata, igraph, edge-list

I am working on igraph in R.

I have a dataframe (df) with 29 columns - some rows which all have values and some which have `NA`s.

It looks a little something like this:

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4
   1   1  2  3  NA
   2   2  3  NA NA
   3   2  4  1  NA
   4   1 NA  NA NA
```

but much larger.  I am having trouble creating an edgelist from this data and have tried:

```
myPairs <- apply(t(df), 2, function(x) t(combn(x[!is.na(x)], 2)))
```

but keep getting this error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :  error in evaluating the argument
> 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': n < m

The output should look like this:

```
      col1   col2
   1  1      2
   2  1      3
   3  2      3
   4  2      3
   5  2      4
   6  2      1
   7  1      4
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: To amplify the comment of KU99,   it is not obvious what the edges should be.  How is that input supposed to be converted to an edgelist?

Comment: I have amended my original post to answer your questions

Comment: You did not explain the interpretation of your original data though, and how it represents a set of connections. I do not see how your example output related to your input.

Comment: Apologies.  The numbers on each row are connected. So for row 1 numbers 1 and 2 are connected, 2 and 3 are connected and 1 and 3 are connected

Comment: We can see from your desired output which rows are connected, but _how_ do you identify those connections from the snippet of data you presented?  Is it that rows are connected if they contain some of the same values?  Do the values of the variables give the row numbers of the connections? In this case, we could see that row 1 has a connection with rows 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.

Making sure your data.frame is numeric:

```
df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

You can use `apply` with `combn` as you've done, but first use `na.omit` to remove missing values. You can also check the `length` so that if you only have one value in a row you skip it.

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- na.omit(x)
  if (length(y) > 1)
    t(combn(y, 2))
}))
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    2    1
[7,]    4    1
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly, I had realised that the issue with my solution was the rows with only one variable in them (which therefore could not make a pair) but had not been able to put together an efficient solution other than creating a completely new dataframe with those rows removed. So your solution is great!